# Magnet and needle

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, classical-electrodynamics

When I place a needle near a clamped magnet and let it go, it moves towards the magnet. Since magnetic field cannot work on individual charge particles, we must conclude that the needle loses its overall internal energy and hence cools down! Is this true?

Comment: Why "must we conclude" the energy loss in the needle?

Comment: Dr, it is not the force between a magnetic field and a charge, but between two magnetic fields.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Force_between_two_bar_magnets

Comment: @KyleKanos If you think of a needle as a collection of ions, isn't it clear that the individual speeds of the ions do not change in the magnetic field. But the needle accelerates as a whole system so it must lose internal energy.

Comment: think of each ion as a little magnet too

Answer (score 1):

The total energy stored in the magnetic field goes down - that's where the energy to move the needle comes from. The "internal energy" of the atoms inside the needle has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What is the "Energy stored in magnetic field"? Sorry for my ignorance. Also, if we view the magnet + needle + table (on which the magnet is clamped + earth etc.) as a mechanical system, who loses energy in the end?

Comment: Magnetic field lines in space contain energy - $\frac12 \frac{B^2}{\mu}$ see for example [this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html). As the needle approaches the magnet, the shape of the magnetic field lines changes - while they will be closer together in some areas (thus higher energy per unit volume), other (larger) regions will have a lower magnetic field. The net result is that there will be less energy stored in the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think that's right, put spins in a magnetic field and they 
fall into the lower energy state, (with a time given by T1) 
it's the first step in magnetic cooling.

Edit:  As Floris pointed out I got this backwards.  As the spins go into a lower energy state the energy they had has to go somewhere.. into the lattice (or needle in this case.)

Comment: In magnetic cooling, the cooling happens when you remove the magnetic field and the ordered atoms become disordered again.

Comment: @Floris, Right!  (my mistake) I'll edit my answer.  (That's what I get for thinking too fast.)